# Themes & Icons not loading after logging in quickly

Tags: unity, themes, icons, lightdm

So this is a funny one, I guess.

What am I running? Ubuntu 15.04 / Kernel 3.19

On what am I running? ASUS Zenbook ux303ln

As the title says, the theme and icon style, specified in the unity tweak tool won't be loaded, if, after startup, I log in TOO QUICKLY. If I wait a few seconds in the login screen, the screen briefly flickers and the theme and icon style correctly load upon logging in. If they didn't load and I log out and back in (or restart lightdm), they will also correctly load.

All the other tweak tool settings work, workspaces, hotcorners, all no problem, only themes and icons, strangely enough.

What I already tried, and didn't work were

```
unity --replace
compiz --replace
```

as well as

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
```

I played around with it a fair bit already, but didn't really find a solution so far. It's more a Quality of Life thing and nothing I will reinstall the system over (well .. maybe), but maybe anybody of you lot has an idea?

Cheers

Comment: I have experienced the same issue on two different systems, one a lenovo yoga 2 pro and the other my Sandy Bridge x79 desktop. Currently I am running 14.04 on the desktop with a custom theme and icon pack, the theme loaded but the icon pack did not and it is extremely annoying. If I log out and back in the issue is corrected. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have similar problem in Ubuntu 16.04 with Numix theme. Did something help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing line 4 of

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/unity-settings-daemon.desktop
```

to

```
Exec=bash -c "sleep 2; /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon-localeexec"
```

This should give a couple of second to unity to think of what to do :D

Comment: sadly, this work-arround seems not work. even with 5 sec sleep.

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting if this doesn't help try updating your computer or try `sudo apt-get update` this should update the repository that it is feeding from.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.
Updating to kernel 4.8.2 fixed it.

I don't know if it could help you or not, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Could you expand this a bit?  How would the OP go about updating his/her kernel?